# Adding javascript buttons to a Modal (javascript newbie)

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm new to java-script and really programming, I'm able to read and understand whats going on but writing code is another issue. It drives me crazy I can't figure out some buttons. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get these modals some buttons?

```
        <div>
            <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
            <a img id="myImg30" src="homefiles/a (30).jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"></a>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                <!-- The Close Button -->
                <span class="close">&times;</span>

                <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

                <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <script>
                // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

                // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
                var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
                var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
                img.onclick = function () {
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                    modalImg.src = this.src;
                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                }


                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function () {
                }


        </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean? In HTML? Or Inserting buttons in JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry the question is not clear. Please explain further and add more details to help clarify what you'd like to happen.